# How can I test the validity of a ReferenceProperty in Appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am currently testing a small application I have written. I have not been sufficiently careful in ensuring the data in my datastore is consistent and now I have an issue that I have some records referencing objects which no longer exist. More specifially, I have some objects which have ReferenceProperty's which have been assigned values; the objects referred to have been deleted but the reference remains.

I would like to add some checks to my code to ensure that referenced objects exist and acting accordingly. (Of course, I also need to clean up my data).

One approach is to just try to get() it; however, this should probably retrieve the entire object - I'd like an approach which just tests the existence of the object, ideally, just resulting in costs of key manipulations on the datastore, rather than full entity reads.

So, my question is the following: is there a simple mechanism to test if a given ReferenceProperty is valid which only involves key access operations (rather than full entity get operations)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will test key existence without returning an entity:

`db.Query(keys_only=True).filter('__key__ =', test_key).count(1) == 1`

I'm not certain that it's computationally cheaper than fetching the entity.

Comment: Thanks - it looks a bit heavy. I was hoping for something a little bit lighter; I'll leave the question open a bit longer in case someone else can propose a tidier variant.

Comment: Drew's solution is actually pretty light. A keys_only query is faster than fetching the entity.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Sure - that was the point of the question, after all. I meant heavy in the sense that it seems to have quite a few moving parts for what seems like quite a basic/fundamental operation.

Comment: Just throw a "def keyExists(test_key):" and a "return" in there, and you're all set...

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I'm not positive that's the case - it certainly depends on the complexity of the entity. I'd love to see benchmarks demonstrating it one way or the other, though.

Comment: Also of note: key-only queries cost significantly less. They're billed under "small ops".

Comment: Given that some heavyweights have bailed into this thread and nobody has proposed an alternative, I guess this is probably the best solution. I still find it surprising.

Comment: @Sean I'm not sure what you're picturing as lighter weight - can you give an example of what a lighter weight solution might look like in a typical application that used SQL?  I'm thinking it would have to have a select query involved, which is already a few moving parts just by itself.

Comment: @PeterRecore - I was thinking of something like this http://php.net/manual/en/function.dba-exists.php - however, having thought a little about the DB side, it's not clear how it could actually be implemented. Regarding lightweight/heavyweight - the `Query` class is designed to facilitate simple construction of queries of the datastore (and iteration over them) - that looks quite different from what I wanted to do here, hence I thought using that mechanism looked heavy.

Comment: This question relates to this question on checking if an entity exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745246/is-there-a-cheap-way-to-check-if-a-entity-exists