# Is there a (cheap) way to check if a entity exists?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have some keys and the only thing I want to know is if there is a matching entity in datastore. currently I'm doing:

```
entities = db.get(keys)
for entity in entities:
     if entity:
           # some stuff
     else:
           # some other stuff
```

While this works, I just need a boolean to be passed, not the entier object. Is there a way to make this bit of code a bit cheaper?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I test the validity of a ReferenceProperty in Appengine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636806/how-can-i-test-the-validity-of-a-referenceproperty-in-appengine)

Comment: not really, I'm trying to fetch several true/false, and he just wants one.

Comment: It is essentially the same technique whether you want to test one or many keys.  The part that makes it cheaper is specifying a query that is __keys_only__.  It is cheaper to grab just the key.  That fact remains the same whether you grab one key or many keys.

Comment: Queries with __IN__ operator can't be keys only. I really don't see how I can apply that to my problem.

Comment: You're not even using a `Query`.  I don't see how the `IN` operator applies to your problem.

Comment: Srry I didn't express myself correctly. Theres another work around in my code that lets me use _Query_. But bottom line, theres nothing I can do here?

Comment: @PeterRecore Actually, doing a get may be cheaper when you want to test for multiple entities' existence in parallel, depending on the size of the entity and the number of items you're checking. That's addressed in the comments of the duplicate question, though.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the speed of what you're doing now against querying the keys one-at-a-time using a keys-only query. If there isn't a clear winner, take the keys-only query, since it costs less.